# how to calculate transition probability matrix for n*4 data

Tags: transition-matrix

data:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ni96jmzn14sjl4/florep_normn4_p1.mat?dl=0

I attached n*4 data. so here each row has 4 values and each row considered as one state. I want to calculate transition probability matrix with this data.

1. transition probability matrix calculated as what is probability of one state follows another and here each row is a one state so how to calculate transition probability of one row follows to another.

or

2. I have to first quantize each row to its closest symbol and then I can calculate transition probability, so how to quantize each row to its closest symbol.

I want to do this with any one approach of above two. how to do it.